# NestJS - JWTModule context dependency

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

After run my app i get this...

```
[Nest] 5608   - 01.01.2021, 18:12:05   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService (?). Please make sure that the argument JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS at index [0] is available in the JwtModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS is a provider, is it part of the current JwtModule?       
- If JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within JwtModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS */ ]
  })
```

can someone tell me what i have wrong with my code?

```
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
    JwtModule.register({
        secretOrPrivateKey: 'secret12356789'
    })
    ],
    providers: [UserService]
})
export class AuthModule { }

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      //
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
    JwtModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, UserController, AuthController ],
  providers: [AppService, UserService, AuthService ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

thanks for any help
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 3):

In your `AppModule` you have the `JwtModule` imported but adding no options to it. This is what's causing the issue. As you already have the `JwtModule` registered in the `AuthModule`, this probably isn't what you're meaning to do.

You have the `UserService` registered in at least two places (`AuthModule` and `AppModule`), you're probably meaning to add the `UserService` to the `exports` of `UserModule` and then add the `UserModule` to the `imports` array of the module where you need the `UserService`.

Comment: I added `UserService` to exports in `UserModule` and `userModule` to imports in `AuthModule` but it not works :/

Comment: Did you remove `JwtModule` from `AppModule` like I indicate in my first two sentences?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR See, copy/paste examples.

Recently had the same issue.
As Nest.JS recommends the `JwtModule` could be declared in an authorization module: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication. And, yes, it should be declared once with all its settings. The topic message could come from a multiple declaration (some of them has no `JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS`). Can wrap [Jay's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576186/jay-mcdoniel) response with a prepared working example.

So the auth module should look like:

```
//./authorization/authorization.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

import { AuthorizationController } from './authorization.controller';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization.service';

@Module({
    imports: [
    ...
    JwtModule.register({
        secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET || 'SOME_SECURE_SECRET_jU^7',
        signOptions: {
            expiresIn: process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME || '24h',
        }
    }),
    ....
    ],
    controllers: [AuthorizationController],
    providers: [AuthorizationService],
    exports: [AuthorizationService, JwtModule]//<--here exports JwtModule
                                              //as a part of AuthorizationModule 
})

export class AuthorizationModule {};
```

Then your `AppModule` will inject the exported `JwtModule` from `AuthorizationModule` in this way.

```
//./app.module.js

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthorizationModule } from './authorization/authorization.module';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
        AuthorizationModule, //<-- here injects the set up JwtModule
                             //NB! No additional injections required!
        ...
    ],
    ...
})

export class AppModule {};
```

Hope, this will help. ;)